# How can I store the types of elements from a list in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

How can I store the types of elements from a list in a dictionary?
for example to make the output like this :

```
datatype_statistic([1,'2',3.5, 0.5, None, (1,1)]) = {
        'int': 1,
        'str': 1,
        'float': 2,
        'None'：1,
        'tuple': 1
    }
```

This is what I did till now but I just do not know what is the method that I should apply to acheive the above :

```
def datatype_statistic(ls):
     my_list=len(ls)
     print("There are "+str(my_list)+" elements in this list" )
     for item in ls:
        print(type(item))
datatype_statistic([1,'2',3.5, 0.5, None, (1,1)])
```

Comment: Creating a dictionary at any point would be a good start, right now you're just printing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def datatypes(lst):
    ret = defaultdict(int)
    for x in lst:
        ret[type(x).__name__] += 1
    return dict(ret)

print(datatypes([1, '2', 3.5, 0.5, None, (1, 1)]))
```

Or, without imports:

```py
def datatypes(lst):
    ret = {}
    for x in lst:
        ret[type(x).__name__] = ret.get(type(x).__name__, 0) + 1
    return ret

print(datatypes([1, '2', 3.5, 0.5, None, (1, 1)]))
```

Output: `{'int': 1, 'str': 1, 'float': 2, 'NoneType': 1, 'tuple': 1}`

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is specifically made for this kind of task:

```
from collections import Counter

ls = [1,'2',3.5, 0.5, None, (1,1)]

def datatype_statistic(ls):
    type_names = [type(elem).__name__ for elem in ls]
    return dict(Counter(type_names))

print(datatype_statistic(ls))
```

Output:

```
{'int': 1, 'str': 1, 'float': 2, 'NoneType': 1, 'tuple': 1}
```

I first use a list comprehension to get the type names from the list elements. Then I just apply the `Counter`. Finally I cast to dict to get the output in the requested form.

### Side notes

Note that the calls to `.__name__` and `dict()` are only there to shoe-horn the result to fit the example given for a desired result. You need to know yourself if you actually need them.

The type of `None` is `NoneType`, so that's what I print. You can special-case this if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
jake_list = [1, '2', 3.5, 0.5, None, (1, 1)]
datatype_statistic = dict()

for i in jake_list:
    tmp_type = type(i).__name__
    datatype_statistic[tmp_type] = datatype_statistic.get(tmp_type, 0) + 1

# {'int': 1, 'str': 1, 'float': 2, 'NoneType': 1, 'tuple': 1}
```

Comment: But that's not the actual output... it's `{<class 'int'>: 1, <class 'str'>: 1, <class 'float'>: 2, <class 'NoneType'>: 1, <class 'tuple'>: 1}`

Comment: Aha, I get your output when I print() the dictionary. If I just type `datatype_statistic` into the interpreter, I get my output.

Comment: I've updated to include `__name__`, like you did.

Comment: Ok, now it's definitely not that output. The keys are now strings - it should be `{'int': 1, 'str': 1, 'float': 2, 'NoneType': 1, 'tuple': 1}`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to employ some form of counter to solve this, which you have not used in your code.

```
def type_counter_list(list_1):
    count_type = dict()
    for _ in list_1:
        x = type(_)
    if _ in count_type.keys():
        count_type[x]+=1
    else:
        count_type[x]=1
    return count_type
```

This is not a code, but I guess you are a beginner. This is a blueprint for you to develop your code on.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using some built-in methods in Python such as [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), and [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

This is the solution for me:

```
your_list = [1,'2',3.5, 0.5, None, (1,1)]
x = list(map(lambda j: type(j), your_list))
types_dict = {i.__name__:x.count(i) for i in x} # A dict comprehension
# types_dict value sould be: {'int': 1, 'str': 1, 'float': 2, 'NoneType': 1, 'tuple': 1}
```